# FileNotFoundException while executing spark job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to execute a program on Spark. I have a cluster with a master and two slave nodes. I am receiving the following error during execution.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 44, hadoopslave3): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-te/dl4j/1485860107978_-4ccc8c8/0/data/dataset_4-4ccc8c8_68.bin does not exist
Driver stacktrace is as follows:
Driver stacktrace:
at og.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
17/01/31 10:56:08 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 45) on executor hadoopslave3: java.lang.RuntimeException (java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-te/dl4j/1485860107978_-4ccc8c8/0/data/dataset_2-4ccc8c8_77.bin does not exist) [duplicate 3]
```

However, I can see all the dataset objects (.bin files) created on the HDFS. Any suggesstions ?

Comment: This `/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-te/dl4j/1485860107978_-4ccc8c8/0/data/dataset_4-4ccc8c8_68.bin` looks like a local file.

Comment: post the spark program

Comment: @franklinsijo: this is the {hadoop.tmp.dir}

Comment: Well that resides in local filesystem. But you have said "I can see all the dataset objects (.bin files) created on the HDFS". Post the code and clarify

Comment: I am trying to execute an example program present at this link : https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-spark-examples/dl4j-spark/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/mlp

Comment: when i execute the program some dataset objects (.bin files) are created on slave1 and some files are created on slave2. During execution it seems that slave1 is trying to execute the files located on slave2. This generates the FileNotFoundException. Any suggesstion how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a cluster with "two slave nodes" set up: do you also have a Hadoop filesystem set up? If not, then that's your issue.

The example you're linking to, when using a non-local cluster, transfers references to datasets using Hadoop. The behavior of this example has been made more predictable (with a [big error message](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/pull/2980)) in release 0.8.0.